# Create a SOAP message that contains an attachment in java

Tags: java, soap, attachment, saaj

My goal is to create a soap client that attaches a pdf file to the request.

Steps:

1. I created a soap message.
2. I added content to SOAPPart.
3. I've attached an attachment to the message.
4. I sent the message.

The SoapUI (5.5.0) mock returns the following error:

> ERROR:An error occurred [Missing operation for soapAction [http://.../..] and body element [null] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]]

The code is very simple. This is what I put together: http://java.boot.by/wsd-guide/ch02s04.html

I compared a request I sent and a request from SoapUi. I found a difference with "content-type" in the start section.

My client:

> Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_Part_1_611437735.1568631410174"; type="text/xml"

SoapUi:

> Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; boundary="----=_Part_26_15392417.1568631333842"

I tried to add it manually but it will be removed when saving the SAAJ message.

```
String xml;
        InputStream is;
        File file = new File(filename);
        String id = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        xml =   "<soapenv:Envelope .................................">\n" +
                "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
                "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
.......................
                "   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>\n";

        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection = factory.createConnection();
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

        SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(is);
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        soapPart.setContent(domSource);
        soapPart.setContentId("<root.message@cxf.apache.org>");


        URL url = new URL("https://../.");
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(url);
        AttachmentPart attachPart = message.createAttachmentPart(handler);
        attachPart.setContentId("<root.message@cxf.apache.org>");
        message.addAttachmentPart(attachPart);

        message.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related; type=\"text/xml\"; start=\"<rootpart@soapui.org>\"");
        message.getMimeHeaders().setHeader("SOAPAction", "\"http://..../...\"");
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);
```